# Activate a Mobile Connect Contact

Tags: api, mobileconnect

Is there a way to activate an unsubscribed contact on SFMC Mobile Connect by using an API?

I tried using queueMO but I can only send STOP message and not a Start/Join.

Thanks.

Comment: Hello Sanchit, did find any solution to this problem ? I'm facing the same issue. Many thanks